# How to combine asymmetric lists the following way

Tags: list, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala - can yield be used multiple times with a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140164/scala-can-yield-be-used-multiple-times-with-a-for-loop)
>   [Cartesian product of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217764/cartesian-product-of-two-lists)

I try to combine some Scala Lists the following way, but no success so far.

```
List (List ("abc", "def"), List ("gh", "ij", "kl"), List ("mnop") ...)
```

-> The result should be

```
List(
List("abc", "gh", "mnop"),
List("abc", "ij", "mnop"),
List("abc", "kl", "mnop"),
List("def", "gh", "mnop"),
List("def", "ij", "mnop"),
List("def", "kl", "mnop")
)
```

Comment: This is called a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). There's an example of how to do it in Scala [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218167/98117).

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5177163/312172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for {
  a <- List("abc","def")
  b <- List("gh", "ij", "kl")
  c <- List("mnop")
} yield List(a, b, c)
```

Comment: It's the right answer, I see no reason for down voting.